# Append output to file: "File not found"

Tags: batch-file, output

I have this line in a Windows batch file:

```
dir /a-d "E:\Reports_PreDelivery\*" && (xcopy /D /V E:\Reports_PreDelivery\* \\ServerName\Folder\Procedures)
```

This all works correctly. I'd like to log the output to a file, so I tried:

```
dir /a-d "E:\Reports_PreDelivery\*" && (xcopy /D /V E:\Reports_PreDelivery\* \\ServerName\Folder\Procedures) >> C:\logs\reports_transmit.log
```

The output redirect doesn't seem to work. The directory listing still shows up in the cmd window (instead of redirecting) and then hits a "File not found" error like it's trying to run `dir` for something incorrectly. I also tried `2>&1` at the end too, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirection is in the wrong place. It is only being applied to the conditional XCOPY command.

Try placing parentheses around everything, and redirect outside of that.

```
(dir /a-d "E:\Reports_PreDelivery\*" && xcopy /D /V E:\Reports_PreDelivery\* \\ServerName\Folder\Procedures) >>C:\logs\reports_transmit.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Fixed my "piping" wording, thanks. Any reason you moved the existing parenthesis around?

Comment: @JBurace - They aren't needed if there is no redirection. I'm assuming you want to capture all output, so that is what my code does. If you just want to capture output of DIR command than move the redirection to before the `&&` operator, and you can drop the parentheses.